# Python vs Go Hashing Differences

Tags: python, hash, go, cryptography, sha1

I have a Go program

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/hmac"
    "crypto/sha1"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    val := []byte("nJ1m4Cc3")
    hasher := hmac.New(sha1.New, val)
    fmt.Printf("%x\n", hasher.Sum(nil))
    // f7c0aebfb7db2c15f1945a6b7b5286d173df894d
}
```

And a Python (2.7) program that is attempting to reproduce the Go code (using `crypto/hmac`)

```
import hashlib
val =  u'nJ1m4Cc3'
hasher = hashlib.new("sha1", val)
print hasher.hexdigest()
# d67c1f445987c52bceb8d6475c30a8b0e9a3365d
```

Using the `hmac` module gives me a different result but still not the same as the Go code.

```
import hmac
val = 'nJ1m4Cc3'
h = hmac.new("sha1", val)
print h.hexdigest()
# d34435851209e463deeeb40cba7b75ef
```

Why do these print different values when they use the same hash on the same input?

Comment: val in python is not bytes ... try `val = b'nJ1m4Cc3'`

Comment: A Python method that reproduces what you have shown in Go now is contained in my answer. `hmac.new("sha1", val)` is wrong: it provides `"sha1"` as `key`, and does not specify the right digest constructor, so that this method actually uses md5 internally. You just need to carefully read the documentation and understand what the `msg`, `key`, and `digestmod` arguments mean in the `hmac.new()` signature. https://docs.python.org/2/library/hmac.html

Comment: You are welcome, it was a good opportunity to use Go again, which I have set up for a while already on my system :-). And, just in case, don't forget to accept the answer :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to make sure that

- the input in both scenarios is equivalent and that
- the processing method in both scenarios is equivalent.

In both cases, the input should be the same binary blob. In your Python program you define a unicode object, and you do not take control of its binary representation. Replace the `u` prefix with a `b`, and you are fine (this is the explicit way to define a byte sequence in Python 2.7 and 3). This is not the actual problem, but better be explicit here.

**The problem is that you apply different methods in your Go and Python implementations.**

### Given that Python is the reference

In Go, no need to import `"crypto/hmac"` at all,  in Python you just build a SHA1 hash of your data. In Go, the equivalent would be:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha1"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    data := []byte("nJ1m4Cc3")
    fmt.Printf("%x", sha1.Sum(data))
}
```

Test and output:

```
go run hashit.go
d67c1f445987c52bceb8d6475c30a8b0e9a3365d
```

This reproduces what your first Python snippet creates.

Edit: I have simplified the Go code a bit, to not make Python look more elegant. Go is quite elegant here, too :-).

### Given that Go is the reference

```
import hmac
import hashlib

data = b'nJ1m4Cc3'
h = hmac.new(key=data, digestmod=hashlib.sha1)
print h.hexdigest()
```

Test & output:

```
python hashit.py
f7c0aebfb7db2c15f1945a6b7b5286d173df894d
```

This reproduces what your Go snippet creates. I am, however, not sure about the cryptographic significance of an HMAC when one does use an empty message.

Comment: I'm trying to keep consistent with existing passwords I have hashed using https://github.com/yhat/phash and furthermore node's password-hash which uses the `hasher := hmac.New(sha1.New, val)` line. But thanks!